# Leetcode 17 : Letter Combinations of a Phone Number

Tags: c++

### Problem Statement

> Given a string containing digits from 2-9 inclusive, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent. Return the answer in any order. A mapping of digit to letters (just like on the telephone buttons) is given below. Note that 1 does not map to any letters.

[image]

```
Example 1:

Input: digits = "23"
Output: ["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf"]

Example 2:
Input: digits = ""
Output: []

Example 3:
Input: digits = "2"
Output: ["a","b","c"]
```

### My Solution

A simple DFS based approach. Ignore some comments that are for my learning purposes (for similar problems to able to code it fast).

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Solution {
private:
  // any auxilliary fields to help us (the "fluff" in the problem)

  std::array<std::string_view, 10> mappings = {
      "0",   "1",    "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl",
      "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"}; // note that 0 and 1 have the digits since
                                     // that makes the most sense

  // private functions that (may) do the heavy lifting
  std::string_view getLettersMapping(char digit) {
    return mappings[digit - '0'];
  }

  void dfs(std::vector<std::string> &combinations, std::string_view digits,
           std::string &s, size_t curr_idx, const size_t &N) {
    //    base case
    if (curr_idx == N) {
      // last digit's combination has already been explored, so simply append it
      // to our set of combinations and return
      combinations.push_back(s);
      return;
    }

    // determine current mapping digit
    auto letters = getLettersMapping(digits[curr_idx]);

    // for that particular digit, generate all the possible combinations by
    // recursing for each possible digit in the next index.
    for (const auto &ch : letters) {
      // note that passing the string s by reference saves space,
      // but now we need to modify it by adding the letter and then removing the
      // latest added later after the  recursive call
      s.push_back(ch);
      dfs(combinations, digits, s, curr_idx + 1, N);
      s.pop_back();
    }
  }

public:
  std::vector<std::string> letterCombinations(std::string digits) {
    //   in the main function, we develop the answer, call the "magic"
    //   recursion/DFS function, and return the answer
    std::vector<std::string> ans;
    if (digits.empty() || digits.size() == 0) {
      return ans;
    }
    std::string s;
    dfs(ans, digits, s, 0, digits.size());
    return ans;
  }
};
```

---

Any suggestions for my code? Also, I'm still learning the more "modern" features of C++ (anything from C++17 onwards), so any such advice would be very welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Make `mappings` `static constexpr`

This mapping should never be changed, so ideally it should be `constexpr`. You also need only one instance of it, so it should be marked `static` as well (also, `constexpr` requires this). So:

```
static constexpr std::array<const std::string_view, 10> mappings = {
    ...
};
```

This also means `getLetterMappings()` can be made `static constexpr`, and in fact you can make `dfs()` `static constexpr` as well, although the `constexpr` part doesn't do much there.

## Redundant check for empty input

Why do you check both `digits.empty()` and `digits.size() == 0`? Those expressions are equivalent. I would just check for `digits.empty()`.

## Unnecessary parameters `curr_idx` and `N`

Since you are passing the input digits to `dfs()` as a `std::string_view` by value, you don't need the parameters `curr_idx` and `N`. Just pass a modified version of `digits` to recursive calls to `dfs()`, like so:

```
void dfs(std::vector<std::string> &combinations, std::string_view digits, std::string &s) {
    if (digits.empty()) {
        combinations.push_back(s);
        return;
    }

    auto letters = getLettersMapping(digits.front());

    for (const auto &ch : letters) {
        s.push_back(ch);
        dfs(combinations, digits.substr(1), s);
        s.pop_back();
    }
}
```